# generate one zip file from three bluej project files

Tags: bluej

I need to generate one zip file from three bluej project folders using 7zip, but I need to produce a zip not a 7zip file.

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: What attempt or research have you put into this?

Comment: Why do you need to use 7z to do this? The "zip" command on the commandline should make this easily achievable ("zip -r9 output.zip input/").

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copying the classes from two of the BlueJ Projects into the third project, and just creating one zip file from that single project?